# Converting a string from a structure into a floating value

Tags: c

I am using `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>`.

fp's text file only contains 420.42

```
fgets(str[0].flo, 7, fp)
```

Has a 7 character string of "420.42" (4, 2, 0, ., 4, 2, \0)

When I try to convert it into a float via `atof()` as

```
float flt = 0;
flt = atof(str[0].flo);
```

The value of flt is not 420.42; am I doing it wrong or is there a different way?

Comment: post the code producing the data in `string[0]`

Comment: The word "float" is reserved. You shouldn't use it as a field name in a struct.

Comment: @Gato As evidenced by StackOverflow's own syntax highlighting :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It helps everyone no end if you post enough code to form an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  The fragment you show can't compile in C; you can't have a structure element called `float` without abusing macros — and if you were abusing macros, you'd not be able to declare `flt`.

Comment: My actual structure names are different as I would not like my code to be identified

Comment: Thank you for the update.  How do you know what's in `str[0].flo` (what printing code have you used to establish its value)?  How do you know the value in `flt` is not `420.42` (what printing code have you used to establish its value)?  Since you've not shown us what you're really doing, we can't tell if you're doing it wrong or not.

Comment: You can post a variant of your code if you don't want your homework to be identified — but if you want our help, you'll need to provide the information we need to be able to help you, or you'll have to go without help.  We're good, but we're not miracle workers; we can't often identify what's wrong in the code you don't show.

Comment: You need to include stdlib.h, else atof() is autodefined as returning an int.

Comment: You see what we mean — once we get enough information from you, your problem becomes trivially fixable.  Until we know enough about your code to know what you're doing wrong, it is irresolveable.  Which compiler are you using, on which platform (o/s)?  If it's GCC, you should be using `-Wall` — and preferably more options.  (I usually use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c11`; I quite often add more warnings on top of that lot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `0.0000` result is likely you have omitted `stdlib.h` in your include list.

Even so, you will get something like `420.420013`, as `420.42` cannot be represented exactly with a 23 bit mantissa.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're only including `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>`, but `atof()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, then you *are* doing it wrong.

You're not compiling with enough warnings set.

You've not got the `atof()` function declared, so your C compiler assumes it returns an `int`, not a `double`.